# Add Javascript to Drupal ../Node/Add/*?

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

Is there a way to add javascript to a node/add page to add some more flexibility in design/functionality?

Ideally I want to modify the naming of buttons of a field collection. Ie. "Add another item" to "Add another group".

I can't get the JS file onto the node/add itself.

I tried updating my theme's template.php

```
function CUSTOMTHEME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode)
{
  if($node->type == 'CUSTOMCONTENTTYPE')
  {
    $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array
    (
      'type' => 'file',
      drupal_get_path('theme', 'CUSTOMCONTENTTYPE') . '/js/***.js',
    );
  }
}
```

JS File to include

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("ID").value="Add another group";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually (unless you changed it), the node/add page uses the administration theme. So you would have to do any changed to that theme's template.php file.

But, you are probably using a core or contrib theme as your admin theme, and it's not advisable to edit core or contrib as your changes will be lost if you ever decide to upgrade, so you should probably make a subtheme of the admin theme, set that subtheme to be your admin theme and edit that.